# Laravel DB 処理　結果の判定処理

Tags: laravel

LaravelのModel
データベースの処理　トランザクションがうまくいったかどうかの判定ってどうやって行うのがBESTですか・・？

```
CertainModel::insert([
         'id'    => $request->id
]);
```

Comment: まずは公式の[ドキュメント](https://readouble.com/laravel/5.0/ja/database.html?header=%25E3%2583%2587%25E3%2583%25BC%25E3%2582%25BF%25E3%2583%2599%25E3%2583%25BC%25E3%2582%25B9%25E3%2583%2588%25E3%2583%25A9%25E3%2583%25B3%25E3%2582%25B6%25E3%2582%25AF%25E3%2582%25B7%25E3%2583%25A7%25E3%2583%25B3)を参照してみてください。そのうえで改め疑問を考えてください。

Comment: またトランザクションを考えるうえで重要なことは「仕様」をはっきりさせる必要があります。トランザクションはあくまで「方法」であり、実際は実現したい「仕様」が存在し、それを解決するための「方法」でしかないです。

Answer (score 0):

トランザクションが失敗した場合例外がスローされるので，コードが終着地点に普通に到達している＝成功です。